# Passport control during travel from UK to Europe

Tags: uk, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, europe

I recently traveled from Manchester to Amsterdam. There wasn’t passport control at Manchester airport, only Immigration at Amsterdam airport checked my passport. Is this normal?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is normal.

The airlines will inform the United Kingdom that you have left and immigration control when entering or leaving the Schengen area is done at the port of entry/exit.

Comment: It used to be the standard, these days you can also be checked when leaving the UK, I have had it done when using the Eurostar train.

Comment: @Willeke for the UK side they only record the ID, they don’t check anything. The Schengen checks are done in London by French officers before departure, this has been the case since the opening of the tunnel. This is called “juxtaposed controls” and is the equivalent of US preclearance, but only happens for travel via the tunnel (and maybe some ferries?), not for flights.

Comment: @jcaron, last time coming home from the UK there was an extra desk where an officer looked at all passports. They may have scanned them, I am not sure on that. The people around me were all either UK or Schengen citizens so there were no stamps to check. This was clearly UK border control, not the French/Schengen, which is after security checks.

Comment: @Willeke The UK has for some reason reintroduced exit checks *only* for Eurostar departures. Apart from that there have been no routine exit checks for the UK since 1998.